# How do I download audio from Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, audio, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have loaded an audio file in Python and I add some white noise to it. How do I download the new file with the white noise in it?

I have attached my code below. Please note that this is being done in Jupyter Notebook.

```
data = load_audio_file("chunk0_1.wav")
wn = np.random.randn(len(data))
data_wn = data + 0.01*wn
ipd.Audio(data_wn, rate=16000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the wav file using librosa, with the [write_wav](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.output.write_wav.html#librosa.output.write_wav) function.

Then in Jupyter you can browse to the file location and download it by checking the box and selecting download at the top.

[image: Example image]

Comment: I don't know how to save the audio file. That is, how do I save the second ipd.Audio?

Comment: If you're using librosa, then it looks like you can write using the [output.write_wav](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.output.write_wav.html#librosa.output.write_wav) function

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jupyter Lab, you should see something like this:

[image]

Left-click the three dots and you should get the opportunity for a local download.  I am currently running GPUs in a specialized kubernetes container with multiple layers of indirection, but I access it on a windows laptop via Jupyter from anywhere, and I can download those individual files direct to my laptop.

I cannot at the moment verify this works on older Jupyter set-ups, but if you're not using Lab, strongly consider upgrading.